# Adding all the files in a folder to build path dependencies using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a Java project in Eclipse with Maven.
Under the lib folder I have many jars and I need to add all of them to the build path of the project. Since many of them change, and so must be included or removed every month, I would like to avoid adding/removing them manually to the build path everytime.

I think repositories could help me, I found something like this:

```
<repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>localrepository</id>
         <url>file://${basedir}/repo</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
```

But then...how do I tell to Maven "add these repository files to the build path"?
I found some solutions where I need to specify the single files, while I'm looking for a way to specify just the folder (it there's a way, preferably with no plugins).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This cannot and should not be done.

Maven expects every dependency to be listed with Maven coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version) in the `pom.xml`.

These dependencies are then drawn from a Maven repository. MavenCentral is configured by default, others can be configured in the `settings.xml`. If you work with multiple people or inside a company, it is a good idea to set up a Nexus/Artifactory server that manages your own artifacts and proxies external ones.

Maven does not like to have "local" jars in folders. It is possible to reference a local jar through the systemPath scope, but it is not recommended.